# Error when searching for friends in search input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" when I start typing friends names in the input form. The error is pointing at this line in Friends.js:

let friendsearched = this.state.friends.filter(friend => {

Anyone that can  have a quick look and tell me where the error is? Thank you!

**Friends.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import './Friends.css'
import Axios from 'axios'
import Frienddetail from '../components/Frienddetail'

class Friendsfollowers extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            friends: []       
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        Axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/friends`,
            withCredentials: true       
        })
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response)
            let friendslist = response.data
            this.setState({
                friends:friendslist
            })
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log("Charles made an error when retrieving all friends: ",error)
        })
    }

    searchFriends(e){ // eslint-disable-next-line
        let friendsearched = this.state.friends.filter(friend => {
            if(friend.username){
                if(friend.username.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())){
                    return true
                }
            }
        })
        this.setState({
            friends:friendsearched
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <h1>Friends</h1>

                <form className="friends">               
                    <div className="titlepart">
                        <label className="friendlabel" htmlFor="friend">Searching a friend:</label><br></br>
                        <input className="friendform" type="text" name="friend" value={this.state.friend} placeholder="Type a friend's username here!" onChange={this.searchFriends}></input>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div className="friendsboxes" >
                    {
                        this.state.friends.map(friend =>
                            <div key={friend._id}>
                                <Frienddetail 
                                    key={friend._id}
                                    id={friend._id}
                                    username={friend.username}
                                    location={friend.location}
                                />
                            </div>
                        )   
                    }
                </div> 

            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default Friendsfollowers
```

---

**Frienddetail.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Frienddetail.css'

class Frienddetail extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (

                <div className="friendbox">
                    <img className="imagedaredevilspicdetail" src="/images/profileimage.png" alt="picturesetting" />
                    <p className="friend">{this.props.username}</p>
                    <p className="friend">{this.props.location}</p>
                    <button className="followbutton">Follow friend</button>
                </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Frienddetail
```

Comment: Try binding the `searchFriends` function. Just add `this.searchFriends = this.searchFriends.bind(this);` in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Convert this function to Lambda function like this

```
searchFriends = (e) => { // eslint-disable-next-line
    let friendsearched = this.state.friends.filter(friend => {
        if(friend.username){
            if(friend.username.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())){
                return true
            }
        }
    })
    this.setState({
        friends:friendsearched
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that in `searchFriends` function `this` will be `undefined` because it is running in the context of window and not the class context.

The `arrow function` is a function without its own bindings.It uses `this` value of the enclosing lexical scope. So defining the function as arrow function inside the class component will bind `this` of the function to the class context.

You must use an arrow function to bind `this` to the class component

```
searchFriends = (e) => { 
    .......
}
```

Or

`Bind` the function in the constructor. In this way you won't have to use arrow function for `searchFriends`

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    friends: []       
  }
  this.searchFriends = this.searchFriends.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: ok interesting! could you please explain me why the previous searchfriends that I had was not being able to bind and the arrow function above makes it work? Would be cool to understand the inner workings